# Getting a series in a chart to have different colours for each series item

Tags: excel-2007, series

I have 10 items:

```
Col1, Col2
One, 1
Two, 7
Three, 45
Four, 2
etc...
```

By default each series is one colour, so each bar in the chart is the same colour. I would like each bar to have a different colour or gradient.

I can do it by switching the labels to be at the side, but I would like the labels of the series to be on the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select a data point (a bar),

Right click > Format Data Point > Fill > Select vary colours by point.

It adds a legend to the right, but you can remove that if you want.

Comment: Actually, just selecting the series and Right click > Format Data > Fill > Select 'vary colours by point' works fine.